# What is the cumulative amount of working hours for consumer products?

Tags: mathematical-economics, labor-economics

Is there any research about the cumulative amount of working hours for consumer products like cars or mobile phones?

With cumulative amount of working hours I mean the total amount of working hours that is spend to create 1 quantity of that product, including research & development, extracting resources, transportation, manufacturing, distributiong, etc.

Comment: Would you include the working hours needed to create the tool needed to create the product? And the working hours spent on research to create the tool to create the tool that creates the product?

Comment: Yes, but only in an amortized way. That means if I can use the tool to produce a quantity of 1,000 products, then I only want to count 1/1,000 of the working time of that tool. If the tool is produced 1,000,000 times, then I only want to count 1/1,000,000 of the research working time of that tool.